Is it possible to set the space characters used around punctuation characters?
In France, there are multiple conventions related to spacing around punctuation characters. For example, some people and entities recommend using the narrow non-breaking space character before colons, but regular NBSP is also commonly used. The same applies to spacing around guillemets, semicolons, dashes, and others.
Does Word allow you to customize automatic spacing around characters?

I know setting the document language to "French" does it for colons and exclamation marks, not sure about the other punctuation marks
